# "getColorDepth is not a function" when running ng command

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I try to upgrade my Angular project (from 5 to latest).

- I installed the latest Node
- I installed the latest npm `npm install npm@latest`
- I installed the latest cli `npm install @angular/cli@latest` (^9.0.7 according to my package.json)
- I deleted my node_modules folder
- I ran `npm cache verify`
- I ran `npm install`

Then I want to run `ng update --all` but I get the following error:

```
D:\DEV\git\ng-brief\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\color.js:14
    process.stdout.getColorDepth() > 1;
                   ^

TypeError: process.stdout.getColorDepth is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\DEV\git\ng-brief\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\color.js:14:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\DEV\git\ng-brief\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\analytics.js:18:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
```

In the file color.js it is written:

```
// Typings do not contain the function call (added in Node.js v9.9.0)
```

But my node version is upper:

```
npm version
{
  myproject: '0.0.0',
  npm: '6.14.2',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '35.1',
  http_parser: '2.9.3',
  icu: '64.2',
  llhttp: '2.0.4',
  modules: '72',
  napi: '5',
  nghttp2: '1.40.0',
  node: '12.16.1',
  openssl: '1.1.1d',
  tz: '2019c',
  unicode: '12.1',
  uv: '1.34.0',
  v8: '7.8.279.23-node.31',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}
```